# is there a way puting variables in controller from an extended framework class?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

hello im still on learning mvc by makeing one, and today i realize that i have a miss on how things work.

```
class Framework
{

    function __construct()
    {
        require 'libraries/language/l.php';
        /*
        $l['hello'] = 'hello';
        $l['helloworld'] = 'helloworld';
        etc
        */
    }
}

class Controller extends Framework
{

    function index()
    {
        #missing ?
        echo $l;
    }
}
```

ok the first question is how can i `echo $l` from my controller files ? is there a way to do that ?

edit* same for this.

```
function library( $lib ){

    if (file_exists('libraries/lib.'. $lib .'.php')) {
        require 'libraries/lib.'. $lib .'.php';

        if (class_exists($lib)) {
            $class = ucfirst($lib);
            $$lib = new $class;
            return TRUE;
        }

        if (!class_exists($lib)) {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for looking in.

Adam ramadhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the data through object protected properties:

```
class Framework
{
    protected $l = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        require 'libraries/language/l.php';

        $this->l['hello'] = 'hello';
        $this->l['helloworld'] = 'helloworld';
    }
}

class Controller extends Framework
{

    function index()
    {
        echo $this->l['hello'];
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah im thinking of that too, i just wanna know if we can do something like above. anyway thanks zerkms! the problem is that l.php contains about 1000+ translated strings.

Comment: @Adam Ramadhan: so? `$this->l = $l;` Doesn't matter how many strings there are.

Comment: well im not sure, because i dont know how $this->var really works from internal, any good source except the php site ?

Comment: @Adam Ramadhan: google for "php copy on write". And this is not related to objects specifically, copy-on-write works (or doesn't work) regardless of kind of variable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that means for each Controller instance, you are going to keep a big array inside it.

Actually, you can make a [singleton class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php) that provides translation for text:

```
class Language
{
    private static $instance;
    public $l = array();

    private function __construct() {
        require 'libraries/language/l.php';
        $this->l = $l;
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $c = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $c;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

And you can have a shorthand function for it:

```
function l($text) {
    return Language::getInstance()->l[$text];
}
```

And then use it:

```
echo l('hello') . "\n";
```

Comment: oh i see, thanks. btw if we use this way where do we put the shortcut ? in the framework class ?

Comment: You can put it in the global level, or maybe the same file as the `Language` class, so you can call `l('stuff')` from anywhere. Think of `l('stuff')` is a shorthand for `Language::getInstance()->l['stuff']`